# Alinhamento Vertical Bootstrap

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Olá, eu estou a criar um site em bootstrap 4. Ao tentar centrar uma secção do meu site verticalmente, isto simplesmente não funciona. Tentei usar já várias formas de centrar o text (flexbox, css personalizado, ...), mas nada parece resultar. O código que usei foi o seguinte:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
      <img src="images/school-portugal.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-8 schools-text">
      <span class="align-middle">
        <h3>Portugal</h3>
        <p>Portugal is represented by OFICINA - Escola Profissional do INA, a school located in the north of the country, in the city of Santo Tirso, district of Porto.</p>
     </span>
  </div>
```

Fico agradecido por qualquer tipo de ajuda que me possam dar.

Comment: Se o que você quer é centralizar o `h3` e o `p` é só adicionar a classe **text-center** do bootstrap aos elementos ou a `div` que contém estes elementos. Tbm está faltando fechar duas divs no seu Html.

Comment: mude `<span class="align-middle">` para `<span class="text-center">`

Comment: o text-center centro o conteúdo horizontalmente e eu quero centrar veticalmente

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/vertical-align/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O grid do Bootstrap 4 é em `flex`, então os **Utilites** que vc tem que usar são os do `klex`, aqui tem a documentação oficial: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/

Basta colocar as classes nativas do Bootstrap `d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center` que o conteúdo vai ficar alinhado no centro! Coloque uma altura de `200px` na imagem apenas para vc pode visualizar que ficou alinhado na vertical direitinho.

Veja o exemplo com o seu código. Não mexi em nada, apenas adicionei as classes nativas que falei acima no `div` que precisava. Exiba em "**Página toda**" para ver melhor o resultado.

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <img src="images/school-portugal.png" width="100%" height="200px" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-8 schools-text d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">

                    <h3>Portugal</h3>
                    <p>Portugal is represented by OFICINA - Escola Profissional do INA, a school located in the north
                        of the country, in the city of Santo Tirso, district of Porto.</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: resultou como queria, muito obrigado!

Comment: @JoãoMartins legal que deu certo ai! Não deixe do consultar a documentação, tem muita coisa lá que vc consegue fazer só com as classes nativas! Boa sorte no projeto!

Answer (score -3):

Para quem estiver usando o Bootstrap na versão 5.2, pode usar a classe:
**d-flex align-content-center flex-wrap**

Documentação:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors